# Kohana 3.x call_user_func() error

Tags: php, callback

i keep on having this error message on Kohana 3

> ErrorException [ Warning ]: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'pages_save' not found or invalid function name

inside my controller i have the following codes:

```
 public function action_pages(){
    return call_user_func('pages_'.$this->request->param('id'));
}
function pages_save(){
    $this->auto_render = false;
}
```

if i would access admin/pages/save i should be redirected to pages_save() function right? but somehow i cant? Kohana keeps on throwing me the following exception stated above. how should i go with this. optimizing is one thing in my mind, if i do switch-case / if-else block it would take me forever if there are too many that i need to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should trust the error message. Which means you did an error. Clean up your code a little:

```
public function action_pages()
{
    $method = sprintf('pages_%s', $this->request->param('id'));
    return call_user_func($method);
}

public function pages_save()
{
    $this->auto_render = false;
}
```

The changes here are only little: Added the missing visibility specifier to `pages_save` and put the methodname into a variable called `$method`.

Now it's getting more visible, that you used a public function name here which is not defined, instead of the class method you'd like to invoke on `$this`. So let's fix that:

```
public function action_pages()
{
    $method = sprintf('pages_%s', $this->request->param('id'));
    return $this->$method();
}
```

This should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's not Kohana, it's PHP that is throwing the error. To use `call_user_func()` from within a class, you need to use the following syntax:

```
call_user_func(array($this, 'pages_'.$this->request->param('id')));
```